# Why can I not put all individual repository methods in the generic base repository

Tags: entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I would like to rephrase this question under an exclusive technical standpoint.

Normally the generic base repository class contains an Add,Delete,Update,GetById and GetAll method.

Now I am tempted to put more methods inside this base class like EntityExists etc... and when I need more specific stuff where I have to drill down the IQueryable.GetAll() method I can just compose/attach the predicates to the GetAll method. This should save me lots of classes and interfaces seen from just a technical side.

But what is the negative impact on my program when I follow this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The generic base repository class should only implement methods that make sense for *all* repositories that may extend it. If you have examples of such methods that won't violate any of the SOLID principles, I'd say feel free to add to this base class.

Without a more specific example (code), I don't think I can provide any more guidance than that.

Answer (score 0):

Base classes are not swiss army knifes or utility classes. SOLID principles applies to them too.

When it comes to repositories you can go two ways. the first one is to use the Specification pattern where you use the same repository class for all entities. What you do instead is to create small specificaion classes which either can be combined or used invidually when querying. Example:

```
repository.Query(new FindLockedUsers(new Paging(1, 50));
```

where `FindLockedUsers` and `Paging` are two specifications (inner classes are `AND`:ed). The implementation is sort of the decorator pattern.

The alternative is to use specific repositories for each entity (root aggregate). These get methods which are customized per entity like:

```
repository.FindLockedUsers(int pageNumber, int pageSize);
```

I personally prefer the latter since it makes the contracts much easier to follow (i.e. I only need to read the repository interface/class to understand how to use it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are following OOP principles, i would say you could do has you wish. Usually i have an interface that declares all that i need my EfDb class to implement. That way, my controllers only talks to my interface and have no direct access to my EfBd class. See an example below:

**Interface**

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    //Person Entities
    IQueryable<Person> Persons{ get; }
    void SavePerson(Person person);        
}
```

**EfDb class**

```
    //Person
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    IQueryable<Person> IDataSource.Persons
    {
        get { return Persons; }
    }


    public void SavePerson(Person person)
    {
        using (var context = new EFootballDb())
        {
            if (person.PersonId == 0)
            {
                context.Persons.Add(player);
            }
            else if (person.PersonId > 0)
            {
                 var currentPerson = context.Persons
                    .Single(p => p.PersonId == person.PersonId);

                context.Entry(currentPerson ).CurrentValues.SetValues(person);                    
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Then in your controller you just call your interface like this and perhaps implement your create actions like below.**

```
 public class PersonController : Controller
 {

    private readonly IDataSource _dataSource;

    public PersonController(IDataSource dataSource)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person model)
    {
       try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                _dataSource.SavePerson(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

I hope that's helpful, sorry for long demonstration but as long as you are following a certain software design principle such as Object Oriented Programming (OOP), all should be okay. It just all comes down to how well you hide your implementation from other classes. Like in my demo, the controller class has no reach to my EfDb class.

Comment: `IQueryable<Person>` is a leaky abstraction. He can simply use the EF context directly in that case.